# Checking if v is a leaf in MST

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I have this question:

Given undirected graph G = (V,E), V ∋ v and non-negative weights W find if there is a minimum spanning tree (MST) where v is a leaf and if there is, return it.

I thought about finding the MST using prim algorithm and check if v is a leaf in it. If v isn't a leaf I will find the second MST and check on it. The problem is the time complexity will be too high. I am sure there is another way to solve this problem but I don't know how. Can you please give me some clue on how to approach this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with *"generate all MSTs and check if `v` is a leaf in any of them"* is that the number of MSTs in a graph [can be enormous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#In_specific_graphs): it could be as many as `n ** (n-2)` where `n` is the number of nodes.

A better way is to observe that all MSTs of a given graph have the same total weight. So a more efficient algorithm could work like this:

- Apply a standard algorithm to find an MST of `G`. Let `total_weight` be its total weight.
- Apply a standard algorithm to find an MST of `G - v`, i.e. the graph without the node `v`. Let `mst_without_v` be this MST, and let `weight_without_v` be its total weight.
- If `v` has an edge of weight `total_weight - weight_without_v`, then add this edge to `mst_without_v` and return it. Otherwise, return `null`.

If the algorithm returns a graph, then it is an MST of `G` because it spans `(G - v) + v = G`, it is a tree (because it was formed from a tree with one leaf added), and it has the correct total weight.

If the algorithm returns `null`, then no MST of `G` exists where `v` is a leaf. Otherwise, deleting `v` from such an MST would give an MST of `G - v` with the wrong total weight.

Answer (score 0):

I think that even if the algorithm that kaya3 suggested is true, it's very hard to write a formal proof for it if you're in course of Algorithms, so I'll suggest a more elegant solution that's very easy to prove. Also, I'll suggest an edit on kaya3 algorithm that makes the proof a little bit easier:

Alogrithm1:

1. Run Prim algorithm **from v** with giving priority to all edges that aren't connected to v. (Giving priority may be implemented for example by adding a very small number to the edges that are connected to v).
2. If v is a leaf in the MST that the algorithm found return true. Else, return false.

I'll give you a hint for the proof that it's true: Since you start Prim from v then it'll for sure pick the lightest edge that goes out of v and then it'll keep choosing other edges that aren't connected to v as long as these edges weight is lesser or equal to edges that goes out of v. If it chose an edge that goes out of v then the MST couldn't be completed without it or that it's weight is lesser than any other edge's weight.